# How to convert strings in a cell array to numerical stand-in values?

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, parsing, cells

In Matlab, I have a cell array of cell arrays created using `textscan` on a tab-separated data file.  Some columns of the data set are strings.  Here is an example array, `'data'`:

```matlab
data{1,1} = {1; 2; 3; 4; 5};
data{1,2} = {11; 12; 13; 14; 15};
data{1,3} = {'Ringo'; 'Paul'; 'The Beatles'; 'John'; 'George'};
```

**I want to convert the string columns to *specific* numerical stand-in values (i.e. 'The Beatles' = 1, 'John' = 2, 'Paul' = 3, 'George' = 4, 'Ringo' = 5).**  Also, it may be important to note that some cells contain more than one "word".

For some context, the entire data set will ultimately be converted from a cell array into one neatly packaged double array (`data = cell2mat(data)`) for easier manipulation.

The only solution I know is to loop through the string array and use a switch statement:

```matlab
vec_0 = data{1,3};
for ii = 1:length(vec_0)
    switch vec_0{ii}
        case 'The Beatles'
            vec_f{ii,1} = 1;
        case 'John'
            vec_f{ii,1} = 2;
        case 'Paul'
            vec_f{ii,1} = 3;
        case 'George'
            vec_f{ii,1} = 4;
        case 'Ringo'
            vec_f{ii,1} = 5;
    end
end

% Replace string column with numerical stand-ins
data{1,3} = vec_f;

% Convert cell array to double array
data = cell2mat(data);
```

Now we have:

```
data = [1 11 5; 2 12 3; 3 13 1; 4 14 2; 5 15 4];
```

What is a more optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you have a specific mapping of strings to numeric values...

Let's say you have a mapping of strings to numeric values as defined in the following 5-by-2 cell array (one mapping per row):

```
numMap = {'The Beatles', 1; 'John' , 2; 'Paul' , 3; 'George' , 4; 'Ringo' , 5};
```

Then you can use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to convert the strings to their mapped numeric values and save it back in `data` like so:

```
[~, index] = ismember(data{1, 3}, numMap(:, 1));
data{1, 3} = numMap(index, 2);
```

### If you need to generate a mapping of strings to numeric values...

You can generate an array of numerical stand-ins with [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), convert that to a cell array with [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), and save it back in `data` like so:

```
[uniqueStrings, ~, numIndex] = unique(data{1, 3}, 'stable');
data{1, 3} = num2cell(numIndex);
```

And `uniqueStrings` will contain the unique multi-word strings from `data{1, 3}`.

### Converting to a double array:

Once you've chosen one of the above options, you can then convert your sample data to a 5-by-3 double array like so:

```
data = cell2mat([data{:}]);

data =
     1    11     5
     2    12     3
     3    13     1
     4    14     2
     5    15     4
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer, but it doesn't completely solve the problem - the user has no way of specifying what numerals stand-in for a given string.  For example, if `data{1,3} = {'Ringo'; 'Paul'; 'The Beatles'; 'John'; 'George'};`, `numIndex` would still return `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]` instead of the desired `[5; 3; 1; 2; 4]`.  I've updated the bolded portion of the question and modified the example to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: @CollinGonzalez: I edited the answer to add an option for using an existing mapping of strings to numeric values.